# Embed QGIS Cloud map

Tags: qgis-cloud, embeddable-web-maps

Is it possible to **embed** a **QGIS Cloud webmap** on to another website?

Currently I'm using a free account on QGIS Cloud to try some new things. Due to restrictions, I only have one database and one map in progress right now. But even in QGIS Cloud Pro (paying license) I'm not sure if embedding a map is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can embed the QGIS Cloud map with the `<iframe>` tag.

```
<iframe src="https://qgiscloud.com/<username>/<mapname>" width="800" height="500">
</iframe>
```